# Transaction was asked to abort because of transaction timeout

Tags: memgraphdb

When I am trying to run `LOAD CSV` into my  Memgraph instance (it runs on remote server, I SSH to it). I get the error `Transaction was asked to abort because of transaction timeout.`

It looks to me that connection is to slow of or something like that. How can I increase the time-out window?